# Limit Treeview selection VBA

Tags: vba, treeview, limit

I would like to limit my Treeview selection to max 8 child nodes. i have a following code it does uncheck the box but immediately after selects the box again. any idea?.

Thanks.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeCheck(ByVal node As MSComctlLib.node)

If Not node.Parent Is Nothing Then
    If node.Checked = True Then
      couT = couT + 1
      If couT <= 8 Then
          'MsgBox node.Text & "_Checked !"
      Else
          node.Checked = False
      End If
    Else
      couT = couT - 1
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Does it behave the same if you start your sub with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and end it with `Application.EnableEvents = True`? You need to do this anyway, because your code calls the same routine again when you uncheck the box, which is non-desirable.

Comment: @A.S.H That's what I thought at first, but the TreeView's `_NodeCheck` doesn't get triggered by vba code (I stepped thru it). Only get triggered via GUI, and changes to the `Checked` property of that Node within the sub will be discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This TreeView NodeCheck object doesn't handle events like other objects, setting the `.Checked = False` has no meaning after the Sub finishes. However, there is a work around using a Public variable and Sub in a normal Module, and most important `Application.OnTime` to do the unchecking (does not trigger the `_NodeCheck` when it's done within macro).

So, in your UserForm module with the TreeView object:

```
Private couT As Integer
Private Const MAX_NODES As Integer = 8

Private Sub TreeView1_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
    Dim bSchUncheckNode As Boolean
    bSchUncheckNode = False
    If Not Node.Parent Is Nothing Then
        If Node.Checked = True Then
            couT = couT + 1
            If couT <= MAX_NODES Then
                'Debug.Print Node.Text & "_Checked !"
            Else
                couT = couT - 1 ' Assuming the scheduled task completes successfully (or move the variable to standard module).
                bSchUncheckNode = True
                iNodeToUncheck = Node.Index
            End If
        Else
            couT = couT - 1
        End If
    End If
    ' Schedule Sub call only if it should uncheck a node
    If bSchUncheckNode Then Application.OnTime Now, "UncheckNode"
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    couT = 0 ' Resets the counter to zero
    '... Other things you have had
End Sub
```

In a normal vba module (change the name of the UserForm and TreeView object accordingly):

```
Public iNodeToUncheck As Integer

Sub UncheckNode()
    ' Assuming this is only be called by the UserForm scheduling
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes(iNodeToUncheck).Checked = False
End Sub
```